# what are the parts that grow out of the top & bottom of a fruit: a stem or stalk and stigma called idiomatically?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

any fruit such as an apple, a papaya, a tomato, etc has the parts that grow out of its top & bottom.

**What are they called idiomatically in general?**

[image]

---

[image]

According to my study, the top could be called "**stem or stalk**" and the bottom could be called "**stigma**". But I am not so sure if they are the common everyday terms that people use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Stem or stalk** is fine. Actually not all fruits *do* have any remnants of the flower persisting at the other end; tomatoes don't, for instance, and neither does the pepper in your illustration. I can't think of any colloquial name for that part of an apple; if you needed to refer to it, it would probably be as 'the remains of the flower' or something.

Strawberries grow out of the middle of the flower, and we call the green part that we pull out the **hull**.

Comment: Not all culinary fruits have such remains, but that is because not all culinary fruit are biological fruit (eg strawberries)